# Multiple workers (same instance) - patterns for figuring out when the work is done?

Tags: c#, queue, task, worker

For a project I need to some heavy work within a few minutes and then continue. Some parts of the process are getting data, others are processing (CPU).

I have three Tasks with a while loop, something similar like this (times 3):

```
private void WorkerA()
{
    int cnt = 0;

    while ( cnt < _TotalAmountOfItems )
    {
        _QueueA.TryDequeue(out var item);

        if ( group == null )
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            continue;
        }

        var result = DoWork(item); // or GetFromDb() or BulkInsert(), etc

        _QueueB.Enqueue( result );

        cnt++;
    }
}
```

And then something similar like:

```
var task_a = Task.Run( () => WorkerA() );
var task_b = Task.Run( () => WorkerB() );
var task_c = Task.Run( () => WorkerC() );

Task.WaitAll( task_a, task_b, task_c );
```

with `cnt < _TotalAmountOfItems` I check in theory if the individual worker is done, so we can close the worker, and in the end get the aggregated result and continue as usual.

I see tons of problems with this though. I.e. that if one WorkerA crashes, that W*orkerB and C will be in a loop forever*.

Before reinventing the wheel I'm pretty sure this problem has been solved in the past. What is the pattern that I need to look for (C#)?

**Important**
In this case I'm bound to a single process. I need to do this for a few minutes and then clean up everything behind me. I can't leave the workers always on.

**On request some more information:**

- Worker A is getting large amounts of data from table storage (in batches)
- Worker B is processing the data (CPU bound)
- Worker C is upserting the data back to table storage (in batches)

Comment: What are `WorkerA` to `WorkerC` doing exactly? That might help spur some ideas.

Comment: Hi @mjwills, I've updated my question!

Comment: `I see tons of problems with this though. I.e. that if one WorkerA crashes, that WorkerB and C will be in a loop forever.` Can you talk us through why `WorkerB` will be in a loop forever  if `WorkerA` crashes?

Comment: Hi @mjwillis, because say there are 10 items, then WorkerB will never receive it's 10th item, `cnt` will always be smaller then 10 and so it will be stuck forever.

Comment: I wonder if you could do something _like_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716412/cancel-child-tasks-when-one-of-them-throws-an-exception whereby a failure in one signals the others through a cancellation token? Or possibly consider using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library ?